# No grub menu after Ubuntu 16.04 installation alongside W10

Tags: dual-boot, lenovo, boot-repair, grub-efi, grub-legacy

I received a Lenovo T460 laptop with W10 pre-installed. I installed Ubuntu16.04 using an USB pendrive. I deactivate the fast boot and select Bios both UEFI and Legacy for the secure boot. But after installation, no grub menu in sight. Even using F12 key, ubuntu is nowhere to be seen... I enter Ubuntu via the USB pendrive and run the boot-repair diagnostic if someone can give me some infos of how to fix this. The boot-repair file is there:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/62CFysxjHC/

I also use the following bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi in W10 without effect.

Thanks

H

Comment: Your Windows is on a gpt parttiioned disk, so in UEFI mode.  Looks like a legacy grub got installed too, so may be Ubuntu got installed in legacy mode.  Check your BIOS/UEFI settings for UEFI boot preference over legacy.

Comment: *'...and select Bios both UEFI and Legacy for the secure boot*. You cannot select both. You can only use one or the other. In your case go back into BIOS and select UEFI, not Legacy. Disable secure boot, then boot into Live Ubuntu and try boot-repair again, then reboot.

Comment: Right. What I meant is that the options for the BIOS are: UEFI only, Legacy only or both. In the "both" option, it goes UEFI first. I'll do the boot-repair again and post it.

Comment: I used Rufus in order to create a live-ubuntu USB. I used the GPT partition and UFEI system. Then I installed Ubuntu again. Nothing changed, no grub menu on sight or ubuntu system when press F12. I again did a boot-repair log of the system. It can be found there: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BnZCjDDZq8/    If someone can help ? Thanks